# Using these methods, how do I check if this entry is in a SQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, forms

I've got an ATM machine and that I've created and it has a Login screen.

You need to be able to log in with the Account Number "1111222233334444" which I've entered into a database and the PIN "7777"
I need it so when submit is clicked it'll check my database and table for these entries and if they're in their it'll continue to the next form. Where would the SQL methods go so that I could check if the entered account and pin number are in the database?  Here's my Open Connection code.

```
 private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {

            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to the server. ");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My CheckCredentials code is this:

```
    public List<string>[] CheckCredentials()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM atmmachine";

        List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
        list[0] = new List<string>();
        list[1] = new List<string>();
        list[2] = new List<string>();

        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                list[0].Add(dataReader["AccountNumber"] + "");
                list[1].Add(dataReader["PIN"] + "");

            }
            dataReader.Close();
            this.CloseConnection();
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            return list;
        }

    }
```

then my Button click code is as follows, most of this is just validation that needs to be changed obviously.

```
private void btn_Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String a;
        String b;
        a = txt_PIN.Text;
        b = txt_Account.Text;
        if (a.Length < 5 && a.Length > 3 && b.Length < 17 && b.Length > 15)


        {

            Login f1 = new Login();
            this.Hide();
            Navigation f2 = new Navigation();
            f2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid PIN or Account Number");

        }

    }
```

for nath

```
public bool CheckCredentials()
    {
        string query = "SELECT 'PIN' FROM atm WHERE AccountNumber = enteredAcctnum";

        string PIN;
        string AccountNumber;


        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string pin = reader.GetString(0);

            }
            reader.Close();
            this.CloseConnection();
            return ???
        }
        else
        {
            return ???
        }

    }
```

Comment: AND What is your question?

Comment: Where would the SQL methods go so that I could check if the entered account and pin number are in the database?

Comment: What do you need the `List` for?

Comment: To check if AccountNumber and PIN are in the database, is there an easier way?

Comment: for reference I followed this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

Comment: Please look at my answer below and see if it gives an idea of what you should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `SELECT *`
Simply `SELECT` the account number column and then compare the entered pin to the matching pin column in the table.

Try something like this:

Call the `CheckCredentials` method passing `b` and `a`. In your log-in form:

```
CheckCredentials(b, a)
```

Now, in `CheckCredentials`:

```
SELECT pin FROM your_table WHERE accountnumber = b
```

You then use your reader:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   string pin = reader.GetString(0);
}
```

Then you can compare:

```
if (pin == a)
return true;

else return false;
```

NOTE: Add two string parameters in your `CheckCredentials(string b, string a)`

Comment: This gaves me a vague idea, think I understand. Can I ask what enteredAcctnum and enteredPin are or, or what they are equal to in my code? :)

Comment: In your code, that's b and a. enteredAcctnum and enteredPin are the information the user entered in your form to log-in. Basically, the user inputs acct no. and pin -> your app then checks if they match anything in the database.

Comment: Do I get rid of the list as well?

Comment: You should. Just declare two string variables for the entered pin and account number.

Comment: Also, you would want to make that method `bool` instead of `list`. Refer to [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/bool-return) to know more about `bool` methods and how you can use them.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions man, really new to SQL stuff. This is what I have, what needs to be changed and what goes where return list was? (edited original)

Comment: See my edited answer. And don't worry, I'm new, too. :)